# Delete lucene index and re-index

Tags: java, lucene

I'm creating a lucene index using RAMDirectory, and then allowing searches to be performed using the index. I also have functionality to re-index when the text is updated. The problem is, if the text changes, the old index is not cleared/deleted.

I've tried using `close();` from `Directory` but that prevents it from being accessed in the future (AFAIK).

How can I delete the old index before re-indexing?

Comment: Source Code would help in such questions... It is unclear what you are doing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-open the index for searching after each document is updated (added/deleted), then searches will find the new document. You don't have to immediately re-index every document when you update (add/delete) a document -- Lucene keeps track of this for you.

Comment: All of these answers are about a single document, but the question is about the whole index.

Answer (score -1):

Calling IndexWriter.update(doc) actually does a delete-add process.

According to its [Documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer%29):

*Updates a document by first deleting the document(s) containing term and then adding the new document. The delete and then add are atomic as seen by a reader on the same index (flush may happen only after the add).*